# How to stop Dropbox Creating Multiple Duplicate Files?

Tags: dropbox

I have two computers sharing the same Dropbox account.

One computer was turned off for sometime, and now after turning it on, Dropbox is creating duplicates of lots of folders and files that had been moved while that computer was turned off.

I haven't opened any of these files on the computer that was turned off for a while but is now on, but I have opened and moved them on the other computer (where these duplicates are being created).

Is there any way to stop this or to prevent it in the future?

I'm not opening these files at the same time on both computers.